# Can't move rigidbody2d when using animations

Tags: unity, physics, animation, rigidbody

I have a player moving and jumping by changing its x or y velocity. It worked well until i created a walking and idle animation. Now, the player is animated correctly when idle or walking, but does not move on the x axis. It can still jump (still using physics), but not move horizontally.

The "Apply root motion" is checked on the animator component, so I don't understand why the character can't move horizontally.

When I disable the animator component, everything works just fine, so why won't my player move on the X axis ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried un-checking "Apply Root Motion"? That setting says "use the offsets in the animation to move my character" so if your animation is in-place and has zero offset, that means zero movement.

Comment: When unchecked, I still can't move and gravity stops affecting the rigidbody

Answer (score 1):

Maybe bcause u controll global X position of player in the animation: "Position.x";
You need to controll only local positions of your object inside animations in this case you will be able to use keys to change global X position of player.